# How do we deploy application from azure devops using Pipelines to azure appservice with a different subscription and organization

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I am setting up a CI/CD Pipeline  for my organization, we are service company who serve a customer who are using Azure Appservice as their platform with their own subscription.

Now we are planning to  buy Azure DevOps subscription by our own and start using it for our 5 projects to build CI/CD pipeline and release pipeline is  targeted to Customer Azure Appservice.

I am sure that  somebody have already done it and what are the challenges in it. Usually when I am doing in the same organization we create Service connections and it works, wanted to know how it works in case of different subscriptions and different organizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create service principal\azure ad users for azure powershell to rely on for silent auth ([examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-1.7.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-)). After that you can just use `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet to do the deployments.

Alternatively you can manually create a service connection for an existing Service principal in customers tenant ([document covering that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal)).